# Toggle text input based on the Select Box Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to do a small JavaScript/JQuery Function

Here is my Code,

HTML

```
<select id="mySelect">
   <option value="YES">YES</option>
   <option value="NO">NO</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="text-input" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" />
```

JavaScript

```
var e = document.getElementById("mySelect");
var strValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#text-input").prop('disabled', true);
  $('select').click(function() {
    if (strValue == "YES") {
      $("#text-input").prop("disabled", false);
      $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
    } else if (strValue == "NO") {
      $("#text-input").prop("disabled", true);
      $("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
    }

  });
});
```

And this is What I need to do here,

1. If User Select YES, then text box will be enabled and user must make an input and should be a number
2. If user select NO then input should be disabled and user can submit.

I am trying to do this but the disabling is not working properly.
Also Please try to help me to make this a numbered input. I can not use `type="number"` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the value of select element in change function and set disabled property as true/false based on value:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#mySelect').change(function(){
   $("#text-input").prop('disabled', this.value == "NO");
   $("#submit").prop('disabled', this.value == "YES");
  }).change();//trigger events once for behavior in beginning 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
<option value="YES">YES</option>
<option value="NO">NO</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="text-input" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" />
```

Comment: The `? true : false` part is not necessary. `this.value == "NO"` evaluates to a boolean.

Comment: if User select NO, The textbox is disabled and Submit should enable

Comment: if user select YES, then he have to input a number and submit button should enable

Comment: @user3199385: you will need to have keyup or change event for input element also. which is complete off topic from select handling.

Answer (score 2):

HTML Code

```
<form action="#">
<select id="mySelect">
   <option value="YES">YES</option>
   <option value="NO">NO</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="text-input" />
<span id="errmsg"></span>
<input type="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

> If user select NO then input should be disabled and user can submit.

```
$('#mySelect').change(function(){
   $("#text-input").prop('disabled', this.value == "NO");
   $("#submit").prop('disabled', this.value == "YES");
  }).change()
```

> If User Select YES, then text box will be enabled and user must make
>   an input and should be a number

```
$("#text-input").keypress(function (e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message
        $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
    }
   });
```

**[Here is the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/t9vq2neo/1/)**

Comment: Need without an alert

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var select = $('select');
    var textInput = $('#text-input');
    var btnSubmit = $("#submit");

    textInput .prop('disabled', true);
    select.click(function(){
        if(select.val() == "YES"){

         textInput .prop("disabled", false);
         btnSubmit.prop("disabled", false);

      }else if(select.val() == "NO"){

        textInput.prop("disabled", true);
        btnSubmit.prop("disabled", true);

      }

    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#text-input").prop('disabled', true);
  $('#mySelect').change(function() {//use change event
    if ($('option:selected', this).val() == "YES") {//get value of selected option
      $("#text-input").prop("disabled", false);
      $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $("#text-input").prop("disabled", true);
      $("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
    }

  }).change();//change on load
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="YES">YES</option>
  <option value="NO">NO</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="text-input" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is not working is because you get the `select` value on page load and not when its changed.

try adding it in the `event` and change it from `click` to `change`:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#text-input").prop('disabled', true);

  $('select').change(function() {

    var e = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var strValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    
    // or use: var strValue = this.value;

    if (strValue == "YES") {
      $("#text-input").prop("disabled", false);
      $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
    } else if (strValue == "NO") {
      $("#text-input").prop("disabled", true);
      $("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
    }

  });
});
```

There are better/cleaner ways of doing this like **@MilindAnantwar 's** answer, but this is why your code is not working.